# Caliburn.Micro assign resolved ViewModel instance to child from parent

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

*controls:TabControlView* is a reusable component. I would need to be able to create a ViewModel/retrieve its instance for each component usage.

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.Views.Shell.ShellView" ...>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

        <controls:TabControlView cal:Bind.Model="{Binding TabControlViewModel}"/>

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

In ShellViewModel constructor:

```
public TabControlViewModel TabControlViewModel { get; set; }
public ShellViewModel(){
    TabControlViewModel = new TabControlViewModel();//For simplicity. It is resolved by IoC
}
```

When I put a break point into TabControlViewModel's constructor I can see that it is being called 2 times.

When I setup IoC to resolve TabControlViewModel as singleton it works (as the internal call for resolving TabControlViewModel is served the same instance).

How should I edit my code so it doesn't call BootstrapperBase.GetInstance() automatically or how can I replace the View's ViewModel?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that as the ViewModel is resolved by Caliburn it is then automatically injected to  property:

```
public TabControlViewModel TabControlViewModel { get; set; }
```

All I needed to do is to make it propfull and do setup of the handed instance there:

```
private TabControlViewModel _tabControlViewModel;

public TabControlViewModel TabControlViewModel
{
    get { return _tabControlViewModel; }
    set
    {
        _tabControlViewModel = value;
        //Init here
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TabControlViewModel);
    }
}
```